# Ad Banner is changing color of layout

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I have Android app with AdMob Small banner on bottom.
I noticed that after Banner is show it change colors of my app and sometimes screen is little blinking.
Any idea what is causing issue  and how to fix it ?
I observed it also in another commercial app.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working.

Add this line to your banner ad .xml code: android:layerType="software"

Comment: Thanks, I will check this.